# NULL in/out parameter in COM

Tags: com

My COM object has a method, in IDL defined as:

```
HRESULT _stdcall my_method( [in] long value, [in, out] IAnotherObject **result );
```

Is the caller allowed to call this method like so:

```
ptr->my_method(1234, NULL);
```

or would the caller be violating the COM specification in doing so?

In other words, should my code which implements this function check `result != NULL` before proceeding; and if so, does the COM spec require that I return E_INVALIDARG or E_POINTER or something; or would it be acceptable for my function to continue on and return `0` without allocating an AnotherObject ?

My object is intended to be Automation-compatible; and it uses standard marshaling.

**Note:** Question edited since my original text. After posting this question I discovered that `optional` [should only be used for VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367132.aspx), and an `[in, out]` parameter where `result != NULL` but `*result == NULL` [should be treated like an out parameter, and I must allocate an object](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~datpete/COT/COM_SPEC/pdf/com_spec.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Rules of the Component Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx) say:

> The in-out parameters are initially allocated by the caller, then freed and re-allocated by the callee if necessary. As with out parameters, the caller is responsible for freeing the final returned value. The standard COM memory allocator must be used.

So, passing `NULL` is a violation.  You can see several violations of COM rules even in Microsoft's own interfaces, such as [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), where a few `[out]` parameters accept `NULL`, but that's because they have remote interface methods (see [`[local]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`[call_as]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that most probably allocate the needed memory when crossing apartments, or otherwise perform custom marshaling.

---

EDIT: To further answer your questions.

I recommend you check for `NULL` `[out]` (or `[in, out]`) arguments and return `E_POINTER` when you find one.  This will allow you to catch/detect most common errors early instead of raising an access violation.

Comment: just clarifying this: the caller must make sure that `result` points to valid storage for an `IAnotherObject *`. For `[in, out]` that stored pointer may either be `NULL`, or a valid pointer. The callee must put a valid pointer in the storage (usually the same one that was passed in).

Comment: Yes, the `IAnotherObject**` must not be `NULL`, as it is a `[ref]` pointer, but its `IAnotherObject*` value may be `NULL`, either when provided by the caller or when set back by the callee, as it is a `[unique]` pointer.  See: [Default Pointer Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373628(v=vs.85).aspx).  Also, interface pointers are always `[unique]`, MIDL will issue a warning if you try to apply some other pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should check for argument validity.

If the client is in-process (and same apartment, etc.) with the server, there's nothing (no proxy, no stub) to protect your code from being called with a NULL.

So you're the only one left there to enforce any COM rule, whether that's considered to be a "violation" or not.

PS: defining in+out (w/o using VARIANTs) for Automation clients seems a bit unusual IMHO. I'm not sure all Automation clients can use this (VBScript?)